# Отправка битов по Bluetooth в Android studio

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

я только начал изучать Java и среду разработки Android studio. Это мой первый вопрос, так что не судите строго. К делу. Я пытаюсь подружить приложение, созданное в Android studio и блютуз модуль HC-06. Код приложения

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buOff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="314dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="70dp"
        android:onClick="Off"
        android:text="Выкл"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buOn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="314dp"
        android:onClick="On"
        android:text="Вкл"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="168dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="402dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.myapplication3;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.icu.text.RelativeDateTimeFormatter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private InputStream mmInStream = null;
    //Сокет, с помощью которого мы будем отправлять данные на Arduino
    BluetoothSocket clientSocket;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();

    }



    //    public void On(View view){
//        try {
//            OutputStream outStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
//            outStream.write(1);
//        } catch (IOException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
//    }
//
//    public void Off(View view){
//        try {
//            OutputStream outStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
//            outStream.write(0);
//        } catch (IOException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
//    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];// буферный массив
        int bytes;// bytes returned from read()

        while (true){
            try {
                bytes=mmInStream.read(buffer);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];// буферный массив
        int bytes;// bytes returned from read()

        while (true){
            try {
            bytes=mmInStream.read(buffer);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

   public void init(){
        String enableBT = BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE;
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(enableBT), 0);

        BluetoothAdapter bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

       InputStream tmpIn=null;
       OutputStream tmpOut=null;

        try{
            //Устройство с данным адресом - наш Bluetooth Bee
            //Адрес опредеяется следующим образом: установите соединение
            //между ПК и модулем (пин: 1234), а затем посмотрите в настройках
            //соединения адрес модуля. Скорее всего он будет аналогичным.
            BluetoothDevice device = bluetooth.getRemoteDevice("98:D3:31:FB:B3:10");

            //Инициируем соединение с устройством
            Method m = device.getClass().getMethod(
                    "createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});

            clientSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
            clientSocket.connect();

            //В случае появления любых ошибок, выводим в лог сообщение
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());
        }

       try{
           tmpIn= clientSocket.getInputStream();
//           tmpOut= clientSocket.getOutputStream();
       } catch(IOException e){}

       mmInStream= tmpIn;
//       mmOutStream= tmpOut;
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CONNECTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//       run();

   }
        //Выводим сообщение об успешном подключении

    }
```

Что я получаю сейчас. При запуске приложения через Debug, я вижу, что по блютузу информация до меня доходит[image: введите сюда описание изображения]  Но при этом приложение **висит на "белом экране"**. При закомментировании бесконечного цикла, приложение "оживает" и выводит компоненты на экран. В чем может быть проблема ?

Знаю, что среди людей, которые ответят будут гуру своего дела, заодно был бы очень рад критике.

Comment: Все просто -- бесконечный цикл блокирует работу главного потока, в котором GUI приложения работает, поэтому окно не реагирует ни на что и не отрисовывает ничего. Решение простое -- бесконечный цикл нужно запускать в отдельном потоке

Comment: Кст, вместо кучи `} catch (...) {` можно использовать один, в нем указать класс исключения, являющимся предком для остальных, попробуйте `Exception`: `} catch (Exception e) {`

Comment: Спасибо, как попробую с созданием отдельного потока - отпишусь.

Comment: @gil9red, не подскажите, как создать отдельный поток ?

Comment: Через класс Thread, а так, тут подробнее об этом: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/thread.php

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо, все получилось.

Comment: Пожалуйста :) Оформите ваше решение в ответе ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ребята, добавляю **еще 1 ответ**, сейчас поясню почему. Ответ выше - подходит в случае, если вы **Не собираетесь** изменять какие-либо элементы приложения (Текстовые поля, названия кнопок, цвет бэкграунда). Если же вам нужно изменять элементы приложения, вам подойдет это решение. **Внимание**, из-за своей неграмотности и незнания терминов, я могу накосячить с описанием, но думаю суть вы уловите.

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        MYAsync myAsync=new MYAsync();
            myAsync.execute();
    }
```

Создаю новый объект класса MYAsync
Вызываю функцию doInBackground(), описанную выше с помощью метода execute();
Описание, что я делал ниже - смотри в конце кода.

```
    class MYAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

                final InputStream mmInStream;
                InputStream tmpIn = null;
                try {
                    tmpIn = clientSocket.getInputStream();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mmInStream = tmpIn;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytes ;// bytes returned from read()
            while (true){
                buffer= new byte[1];
                try {
                    bytes= mmInStream.read(buffer);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
               String str = buffer.toString();
                publishProgress(str);
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            text.setText(values[0]);
        }
    }
```

Смотри, Есть такая вещь - **UI (юзер интерфейс)** - по факту **это и есть все те кнопки,
текстовые поля итд, которые ты хочешь использовать в коде**. Я использовал **2 метода** класса **doInBackground()** и **onProgressUpdate()**. **Зачем?** Все дело в том, что функция **doInBackground()** **не имеет доступ к тому самому UI** и не может менять допустим текст в
текстовом поле, **но зато она используется** для другого - **для долгих/сложных вычислений**,  **но вот onProgressUpdate() - может изменять UI**. Спросишь меня- **как же передать значение в  onProgressUpdate() из onProgressUpdate()**. **Вот так. publishProgress(str);** Лично я передаю переменную str, ее тип я указал на самом верху, при описывании класса class MYAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>. Дальше , я принимаю переменную protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values). values и есть та самая str. И изменяю текст TextView вставляя в него values[0]. Поскольку в моем случае str - это стринг массив. Описал, как было бы понятно мне (очень подробно).

Answer (score 1):

Была добавлена функция mainProcessing() в OnStart()
Код

```
 @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mainProcessing();
    }
```

Далее, добавил отдельный поток следующим кодом и засунул в него ту часть кода, которая отвечает за получение данных в реальном времени

```
    // Этот метод вызывается из главного потока GUI.
    private void mainProcessing() {
        // Здесь трудоемкие задачи переносятся в дочерний поток.
        Thread thread = new Thread(null, doBackgroundThreadProcessing,
                "Background");
        thread.start();
    }
    // Объект Runnable, который запускает метод для выполнения задач
// в фоновом режиме.
    private Runnable doBackgroundThreadProcessing = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            backgroundThreadProcessing();
        }
    };
    // Метод, который выполняет какие-то действия в фоновом режиме.
    private void backgroundThreadProcessing() {
        final InputStream mmInStream;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        try {
            tmpIn = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[38];
        int iterator = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                int bytesAvailable = mmInStream.available();
                if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                    byte[] curBuf = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                    mmInStream.read(curBuf);
                    for (byte b : curBuf) {
                        if (b == (byte) 0xAA && iterator == 38) {
                            iterator = 0;
                            bytes[iterator] = b;
                        } else {
                            bytes[iterator] = b;
                            text.setText(b);
                        }
                        iterator++;
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```